# does anyone know if we can upload screenshots to Azure DevOps with TestCafe CICD pipeline?

Tags: azure, testing, screenshot, devops, testcafe

I am setting up CICD pipeline using this link from testcafe
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/continuous-integration/azure-devops.html#configure-build-task-on-azure-devops-server

it is working as described on Azure DevOps but I am hoping to upload/attach screenshot of the failure with the testcase on the test run. I haven't find anything with which I can do that. does anyone has tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [**`Extension`**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Genetec.publish-test-result-screenshot). This extension provides a Build task to integrate in your continuous integration pipeline. This task will upload screenshots to test result reports from sources other than Visual Studio Test (TRX), for instance, from jUnit.

Comment: I haven't tried this one, but I will try and will update here later. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Did that extension work for you @Drashti?